# What is the best way to calculate the duration from incode/outcode in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have written the following to calculate the duration from incode/outcode but was wondering if there was a better way of calculating this.

As TIMEDIFF() is a time specific  function, I was only able to use it to calculate the difference between the fist 9 characters. I then subtract the last two characters and add them back to the 'Duration'.

HH:MM:SS:FF (FF for frames) and the framerate is 25fps.

```
incode = '10:00:01:00'
outcode = '10:01:05:02'

select CONCAT(SUBSTR(TIMEDIFF(outcode, incode), 1, 8), ':', 
LPAD((SUBSTR(outcode, 10, 11) - SUBSTR(incode, 10, 11)), 2, 0)) as 'Duration';
```

Duration should be:
`00:01:04:02`

**MySQL Version: 5.5+**

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @RaymondNijland i disagree with both parts of that assessment

Comment: Well @Strawberry you might be right.. The topicstarter should provide a table structure with some example data.. Hard to suggest a other method without knowing the structure.. Mine first thought was to separate the FF part from the HH:MM:SS so you don't have to use `SUBSTR` annymore.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ordinarily, I'd agree with you. But this question is really about working with custom timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 5.5.x or later then you can consider the following...

```
SET @timecode_2 = '10:01:05:02';
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@timecode_2,':',3))+SUBSTRING_INDEX(@timecode_2,':',-1)*0.04) x;
```

Outputs:

```
x
10:01:05.0800000
```

Comment: The minimal required MySQL version to run this MySQL code is 5.5+ not 5.7+

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the correction - I'm still using 5.0 :-(

Comment: if you upgrade download MySQL 8.0 :-D